# Pandas: Extract rows of a DF when a column value matches with a column value of another DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DF1 and DF2 as mentioned below. The first column 'POS' of both dataframe might have matches but other columns will be different. I want to compare the 'POS' column of both dataframes, if a 'POS' value of DF1 is in DF2 'POS' column the I want to store that row in new DF1 dataframe and do the same for DF2. I could this easily with a dictionary by keeping POS as keys and compare them to get corresponding values. But the dictionary will not accept duplicate 'POS' values so I am wondering if there is a solution in Pandas DF.

```
df1 = 
   POS   id    freq
0 100 "idex" 3.0
1 102 "ter" 2.0
2 102 "pec" 4.0
3 103 "jek" 4.0
4 104 "jek" 4.0


df2 = 
   POS   id    freq
0 100 "treg" 3.0
1 102 "dfet" 2.2
2 102 "idet" 7.0
3 108 "jeik" 1.0
4 109 "jek" 4.0

Expected:
new_df1 = 
   POS   id    freq
0 100 "idex" 3.0
1 102 "ter" 2.0
2 102 "pec" 4.0


new_df2 = 
   POS   id    freq
0 100 "treg" 3.0
1 102 "dfet" 2.2
2 102 "idet" 7.0
```

Comment: Can you please do a better job of making these Frames copy pastable? Either full lists, or paste the output of `df.head()`, not both.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks a lot for fixing them @sacul

Comment: It sounds like you want to join on one condition (df1.POS==df2.POS) and keep the first dataframe, and then do the same for the second dataframe. Is that the extent of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `isin` for both dataframes:

```
new_df1 = df1[df1.POS.isin(df2.POS)]

new_df2 = df2[df2.POS.isin(df1.POS)]

>>> new_df1
   POS    id  freq
0  100  idex   3.0
1  102   ter   2.0
2  102   pec   4.0
>>> new_df2
   POS    id  freq
0  100  treg   3.0
1  102  dfet   2.2
2  102  idet   7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are describing a classic join problem.
I would recommend the `.merge()` method:

`df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='POS')`

this will return a new data frame with df1.POS as index. all columns from df2 will be in df1, but only for POS values that match. You can play around with the `how=` parameter in oder to get what you need. For more information, see [types of sql joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)